# Knockoutjs Find clicked Button id in table

Tags: knockout.js

I've a Button in table like this

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Items">
    <tr data-bind="css: { alt: $index() % 2 }">
        <td style="width: 60%;" data-bind="    html: ItemName"></td>
        <td data-bind="    html: Quantity"></td>
        <td style="align-items: center; text-align: center;">
            <input id="btnReady" type="button" value="Ready" class="button" data-bind="click: readyItem " /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and my view is like this

```
function MenuItem(data, hub) {
var self = this;
data = data || {};

// Persisted properties
self.Id = data.Id;
self.ItemId = data.ItemId;
self.OrderId = data.OrderId;
self.ItemName = ko.observable(data.ItemName || "");
self.Quantity = ko.observable(data.Quantity || "");
self.Notes = data.Notes || "";
self.Status = data.Status;
self.error = ko.observable();

self.hub = $.connection.postHub;

self.readyItem = function () {
    self.hub.server.itemReady(self.ItemId, self.OrderId).done(function () {
        $('#btnReady').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }).fail(function (err) {
        self.error(err);
    });
}}
```

when I click the above button then always first button in table disabled.
How do I disable the clicked one. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the readyItem handler with this:

```
self.readyItem = function (data, event) {
    self.hub.server.itemReady(self.ItemId, self.OrderId).done(function () {
        $(event.target).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }).fail(function (err) {
        self.error(err);
    });
}}
```

Also, ids are meant to be unique on a page. If you have several rows that contain a button, don't use the #btnReady id for all of them. Make the id unique for each button, or use a class.

Answer (score 1):

Use Knockout's `disable` binding rather than manually manipulating the DOM.

In each item, add

```
self.isReady=ko.observable(false);
```

in `self.readyItem`, replace the DOM manipulation with

```
self.isReady(true);
```

in your HTML, add

```
disable: isReady
```

to the data binding on your `<input>`, and remove the `id` attribute.